# What does $\mathcal{N}$ refer to in Gauge theories?

Tags: terminology, gauge-theory, supersymmetry, definition

Context: I am a second-year (undergraduate) physics major applying for a summer research position. The investigator is working on Quiver Gauge Theories and in response to my inquiry email he told me to

> "compute the HS for the Coulomb branch of 3D $\mathcal{N}=4$ $U(1)$ gauge theory with $n$ flavors."

Assuming HS is short for Hilbert Series, I think I am approaching an understanding of what the problem is asking of me, however I cannot seem to find any concrete description of what $\mathcal{N}$ refers to. Help?

Comment: Second-year *undergrad*? Or second-year grad student?

Comment: See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N_%3D_4_supersymmetric_Yang–Mills_theory for an explanation of N. I would run away as fast as I could from this investigator if he or she is not going to spend time with you to get you up to speed.

Comment: @G.Smith I'm an undergrad. The position description stated that students of all levels of knowledge are encouraged to apply, but willingness to learn is a must; therefore I suspect that this is just some test to see if I am willing to tackle a problem with which I am unfamiliar. At least, that's what I hope.

Comment: If the investigator is encouraging students with all levels of knowledge to apply, then I would go for it. Good luck!

Comment: This paper seems very relevant to your project: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.2657.pdf.

Comment: I've been trying to read through that one actually, trying to chew it down to size haha

Comment: Not to rain on your parade, but 95% of undergrad research projects lead to nothing because the undergrad jumps to a super advanced topic. I’ve seen this play out a hundred times. If you don’t already know quantum field theory, it’s not going to be a productive summer, for either learning or research. If you want to learn, it would be much much more efficient to read a textbook instead. If you want to see what research is like, you could try a topic with fewer prereqs.

Comment: I've thought about that, which is why this project is third on my list of three preferences. Still, I'd like to have the backup option.

Answer (score 0):

In a [supersymmetric gauge theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetric_gauge_theory), N is the rank of the [R-symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-symmetry) group. If N is 4, it means that the theory is invariant under four different but related supersymmetry transformations.

Comment: I am out of my area of expertise here. If I got this wrong, I hope an expert will correct me.